# Power shell Invoke remote script is not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to invoke a remote bat file from my local machine that should start and run the bat in a remote machine terminal. My script is able to connect and show me the output. However, it is invoking the remote bat file but waiting on my screen with bat file output. and my idea is the bat file should invoke and running in the remote machine rather than showing the output on my terminal local terminal. What should be the way here?

loop{

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock { Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c 'C:\apacheserver.bat'"   }
}

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want the .bat file to not show you the result. If so, you should do it with the [Out-Null](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-null?view=powershell-7.1) or by redirecting *STDOUT* and *STDERR* to *NULL*.

IE:  Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c 'C:\apacheserver.bat'" | Out-Null

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. It should just invoke that bat file. And after I trigger the powershell script and after login into that remote machine I should see that bat file should be running ..how can I achieve this?  In my case I see the output in my local console(where I trigger powershell script).

Comment: The script to invoke apacheserve.bat should run in the remote machine background and no need for it to show output on my local screen where i triggered the script from.

Comment: One more thing is so basically it is invoking first servers bat file and it is not moving further to next servers bat invokation......It is stays still showing first servers bat file started and it’s output.  It is never moving to next servers invokation

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to suppress the output from the .bat file inside your local console? If so, redirecting to some form of `$null` is the way to go. You also shouldn't need `Invoke-Expression` as `Invoke-Command` can run the file directly:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop -Scriptblock {
    cmd.exe /c 'C:\apacheserver.bat' | Out-Null
}
```

You could also use `> $null` instead of `Out-Null` if you prefer.

If you want to redirect the output of the `Invoke-Command` call to the remote console instead, that kind of defeats the purpose of the cmdlet. You could try redirecting the console output to a file on the remote computer if you want a local record:

```
$remoteFile = '\\server\C$\Path\To\Output.txt'
 Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop -Scriptblock {
        cmd.exe /c 'C:\apacheserver.bat' > $remoteFile
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you want to run the script in the background and not wait for it:

```
Invoke-Command $computer -Credential $cred { start-process C:\apacheserver.bat }
```